# Set a friendly name for a package when installing using with_items loop

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible task that installs several packages by a direct RPM link:

```
- name: Install packages by a direct RPM
  become: true
  package: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.rpm
    - https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_x86_64.rpm
```

When I run it, the output is as follows:

```
TASK [Install packages by a direct RPM] *******************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.rpm)
ok: [localhost] => (item=https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_x86_64.rpm)
```

Is it possible to change it so that output will print a friendly name of a package, like "Skype", "Zoom", etc. instead of an URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is not what you should actually do (see below), this can be achieved by [adding control to your loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#adding-controls-to-loops) and modifying your package list a bit.

```
- name: Install packages by a direct RPM
  become: true
  package:
    name: "{{ item.link }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - link: https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.rpm
      name: Skype
    - link: https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_x86_64.rpm
      name: Zoom
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

Meanwhile, this is still bad practice in this case because you should not loop over agnostic `package` and alike specific [`yum`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html), [`apt`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html)... modules. You can pass the list of packages to install directly in the name option. The documentation for this is lacking for `package` but is clearly explained on the specific modules pages.

This is how to achieve the same result as above with a better performance (one single call to yum/dnf on the system) and less potential errors (cross dependencies between packages in the list...).

```
- name: Install Skype and Zoom by direct RPM
  become: true
  package:
    name:
      - https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.rpm
      - https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_x86_64.rpm
    state: present
```

If you still want to be dynamic for the names and link list in case you want to add more packages to the task later, here is an example of a possible way to handle that:

```
- name: Install from rpm link ({{ packages | map(attribute='name') | join(', ') }})
  vars:
    packages:
      - link: https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.rpm
        name: Skype
      - link: https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_x86_64.rpm
        name: Zoom
  package:
    name: "{{ packages | map(attribute='link') | list }}"
    state: present
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The last code snippet indeed shows the package name, but it's a bit difficult for me to understand that logic, so I decided not to use it for simplicity reasons.
But also thank you for an advice to avoid using the `with_items` loop. It's indeed has increased the playbook execution time.